# Declaring method matches interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a class with a bunch of methods with the same signature.

```
class Foo {
  method1(foo: string): number { return 42; }
  method2(foo: string): number { return 99; }
}
```

I can define an interface for the method signature:

```
interface Method { (foo: string) => number; }
```

I would like to avoid repeating the signature over and over again for each method. I know that if I am assigning a variable I can say

```
const fn: Method = foo => 99;
```

But how can I do this when defining a method? I would like to get the equivalent of

```
class Foo {
  method1: Method(foo) { return 42; }
  method2: Method(foo) { return 99; }
}
```

but that obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how can I do this when defining a method

Just like you did with a variable

```
class Foo {
  method1: Method = (foo) => { return 42; }
  method2: Method = (foo) => { return 99; }
}
```

NOTE: this does make it a *member* (instead of the method) but the performance implications are *insignificant*.

Comment: So weird mixing lamdas and blocks with returns...
`method1: Method = (foo) => 42;`

Comment: I presume that if the method uses `this` then this needs to be `method1: Method = function(foo) { return this.magic; };`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see how to make this work if I also want to place a decorator on the method.